# Localization with NHibernate

Tags: .net, nhibernate, orm, localization, nhibernate-mapping

Hi guys
I'm a new to NHibernate. I just started development of my next project using NHibernate. One of the requirements is that entity classes should be localized. I'm doing localization the following way:
 - Every entity which should be localized is split into 2 table and 2 entities. For example, I have an entity Service which holds some information, and another entity ServiceLocale which holds localized properties, such as Name, description etc. Same goes for tables.

- Service has a protected field which holds a list of ServiceLocales. ServiceLocale has a property Culture which specifies which language the object belongs.
- The list of ServiceLocale is loaded eagerly from xml mapping file. So when Service is loaded from database, all ServiceLocales also is loaded for this service object.
- Service has public properties, Name and Description. From this properties, I check what's current culture, load appropriate ServiceLocale object and return ServiceLocale's Name and Description.
- Service is persisted using a repository. The repository checks saves or updates the service, and also all of it's ServiceLocale objects.

So my question is: is there a better way to achieve this kind of transparent localization via NHibernate?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok guys, for whom whos interested in answer, I have one.
Jason Meckley wrote me about the solution on nhibernate newsgroup. Looks like it's best to use nhibernate filters.
Here's his answer:

*if you mean to load all the locals any time you query the primary entity, that's a preformance problem waiting to happen. now it may work if you introduce a filter which can be set right after the session opens. this way only a single result is returned per localized resource. it would also bleed into your domain model.*

```
//class
private ISet<string> localizedvalues;
public string Value{get{return localizedvalues.FirstOrDefault();}}

//mapping
<class name="myentity">
   <set name="localizedvalues" access="field" lazy="false" join="fetch">
         <filter name="CultureFilter" />
         ...
   </set>
</class>
<filter-def name="CultureFilter" condition="cultureId = :culture">
   <param name="culture" type="string" />
</filter-def>

//session configuration
var session = factory.Open();
session.EnableFilter("CultureFilter").SetParameter("culture", Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.LCID);
```

this is similar to how ayende's examples works, except we are using a set instead of a formula to pull the locale.

Comment: According to Ayende: "Please note that this is no longer supported behavior in NHibernate 2.1 and up. It was a hack to begin with, and it isn't guaranteed to continue working." http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2006/12/26/LocalizingNHibernateContextualParameters.aspx

Comment: ayende's solution is different. it's using formulas to populate localized data which is inefficient. I'm using join to fetch locale table. So it follows mapping/caching rules. BTW, I'm using it with NHibernate 3 and didn't found a better way to do localization. If you know one, please share it